# How to distinguish Multiple Keyboards in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, keyboard

I have two keyboards attached to a PC. One is used to type in TMemo1 and the other in TMemo2. Both are allowed to type at the same time. The problem is I cannot distinguish what keyboard-one has typed and what keyboard-two has typed.

Is there any way to distinguish, which device certain input came from?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

@Dian, you can use the [RegisterRawInputDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to register the keyboards and monitor the [WM_INPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to determine the device (keyboard) where the input came from.

check theses links for more info

- [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/rawinput.aspx)
- [WM_INPUT Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm guessing I'll have to make a delphi version of the C# code? *sigh* I'll try. 
Thanks for answering! :D

Comment: I had NO idea you could do this in Windows at all.

Comment: @Dian Had any success with porting this to Delphi? Would love to see an example, can't seem to get it working myself.. :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to distinguish keyboards unil you have hooked keyboard driver. Windows provide solid input model to application, so there is no difference for application receiving input from keyboard, second keyboard, IR remote control, or from another program that uses SendInput API function.

Comment: This is wrong. [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) allows you to discern input from different input devices. Using a low-level keyboard hook you can also distinguish between genuine input and input from a call to `SendInput`. The *flags* field of the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) structure carries this information.