# win32api move mouse virtually

Tags: python, winapi, mouse, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a mouseclick with python

My code is the following:

```
class Mouse(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x_res = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
        self.y_res = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)

    def rightClick(self, x, y):
        nx = x*65535/self.x_res
        ny = y*65535/self.y_res
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,nx,ny)
        win32api.Sleep(200)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
        win32api.Sleep(200)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,x,y,0,0)
        win32api.Sleep(700)
```

I use the code like this:

```
mouse = Mouse()
win32api.Sleep(2000)
x = 2520
y = 414
mouse.leftClick(x, y)
```

However this moves the real mouse, so it is disturbing the user. Is they a way to send that event but without moving the mouse for real ?

Comment: Am I the only one who visualized "this moves the real mouse" to mean user has hand on mouse and it scurries to a different location across the mouse pad?

Comment: That said, I believe you have to just make a note of the original location, move the cursor, click, and move it back

Comment: There is usually only one mouse in Windows. So I agree with @mhlester. But maybe you can add a second mouse.

Comment: The real problem off the question is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198792/create-a-poker-table-scanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on faking input to automate this action, then you are stuck with you current problem. When you fake input, the system will respond as it would for real input. You can the cursor back to its original location, but the user is going to see it flicking about. It's really not a good thing to do.

What you need is a solution to your problem that does not involve faking input. Of course, you did not elaborate the problem, only your solution, so we have to guess at the problem. It looks like you are trying to automate some external application. The platform provides support for that via UIAutomation.

Comment: Ok, I will post the actual problem rather than asking for more specific application in 30 minutes or so

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198792/create-a-poker-table-scanner

Comment: Can we deal with this question first?

Answer (score 0):

See [Multiple mouse/mice/cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089851/multiple-mouse-mice-cursor), which refers to [Windows MultiPoint Mouse SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/developer.aspx). The CPNMouse project no longer exists, AFAICT.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted explain why? If there are two mouse cursors then one can be moved on demand to click on buttons, leaving the user's mouse pointer where it was. So although the other answer is likely better, I don't think my answer is wrong.