# Create a poker table scanner

Tags: python, ui-automation, poker

I'm trying to build a table scanner for the software pokerstars ([this is totally legal](http://www.pokerstars.fr/poker/room/terms/prohibited/)).

The software looks like this: [image]

The two parts that are interesting for the software are highlighted in orange. On the left part are all off the table names, on the right part are the players names off the currently active table.

I will call the left part `tableView`, and the right part `playerView` for later on

On the `tableView`, you can select which table you would like to see. You then see all the players sitting at that table in the `playerView`. What I would like to retrieve is basically a 2-dimenstional array:

```
[
    {
        "table": "Aeria IV",
        "players": [
            "careu82",
            "Noir_D€sir",
            "Onyon666",
            "plz542",
            "pripri17",
            "yataaaaaaaa"
        ]
    },
    {
        "table": "Aase III"
            "players":[...]
    },
    ...
]
```

To achieve this, I imagined the following process that I would like to automate:

1. move up to the first table in `tableView`
2. wait till the player names of that table show up in `playerView`
3. retrieve the tableName in `tableView` and the playerNames in `playerView`
4. move down to the next table in `tableView`
5. Do (2.) unless we reached the end off `tableView`

The programm I made so far uses UIAutomation.

It parses all the open windows (Chrome, paint, Pokerstars software) to find a window where the title contains "Lobby". This is the role of the function `forEachWindow`.

For the window that contains Lobby, it will look into all the UI Elements `forEachUIElement`. I'm for now retrieving the childcontent views of the pokerstars window: `iuia.controlViewWalker.GetFirstChildElement(starsWindow)`, storing their position and width and height using `uiElement.CurrentBoundingRectangle` and their className using `uiElement.CurrentClassName`.

I'm then creating white windows with the same width/position as the UIElements to see which element is where.

[image]

As you can see, the two *interesting* elements are of class `PokerStarsListClass`

The code that does all of this is here:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys ,comtypes
from comtypes import *
from comtypes.client import *

# Generate and import a wrapper module for the UI Automation type library,
# using UIAutomationCore.dll
comtypes.client.GetModule('UIAutomationCore.dll')
from comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient import *

# Instantiate the CUIAutomation object and get the global IUIAutomation pointer:
iuia = CoCreateInstance(CUIAutomation._reg_clsid_,
                        interface=IUIAutomation,
                        clsctx=CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)

rawView=iuia.rawViewWalker
controlView=iuia.controlViewWalker


def forEachUIElement(content_element,searchedClass=""):
    list=[]
    uiElement=controlView.GetFirstChildElement(content_element)
    while(uiElement!=None):
        try:
            rectangle=uiElement.CurrentBoundingRectangle
            width=rectangle.right-rectangle.left
            height=rectangle.bottom-rectangle.top
            y= rectangle.top
            x= rectangle.left
            className=str(uiElement.CurrentClassName)
            print className
            if searchedClass in className:
                list.append([uiElement,x,y,width,height,className])
        except Exception:
            ''
        try:
            uiElement=controlView.GetNextSiblingElement(uiElement)
        except Exception:
            uiElement=None
    print 'finish'
    return list

def forEachWindow(root_element):
    window=rawView.GetFirstChildElement(root_element)
    while(window!=None):
        try:
            windowName=window.currentName
            if 'Lobby' in windowName:
                print 'found'+windowName
                uiElements=forEachUIElement(window)
        except Exception:
            ''
        try:
            window=rawView.GetNextSiblingElement(window)
        except Exception:
            window=None
    return uiElements


class WindowOverLayer(QWebView):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(WindowOverLayer, self).__init__()
        self.parent=parent
        self.show()
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.parent.quit()

desktop = iuia.getRootElement()
uiElements=forEachWindow(desktop)
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
windowOverLayers=[]
for uiElement in uiElements:
    content= str(uiElement[5])
    windowOverLayer= WindowOverLayer(app)
    windowOverLayer.resize(uiElement[3],uiElement[4])
    windowOverLayer.move(uiElement[1],uiElement[2])
    windowOverLayer.setHtml(content)
    windowOverLayers.append(windowOverLayer)

app.exec_()
```

Given that I can now select the UIElements that are of class `PokerStarsListClass`, and say the two elements are stored in `tableView` and `playerView`, how can I automate the process ?

Here are also more infos about `tableView`, using the content properties:

```
CurrentAcceleratorKey: 
CurrentAccessKey: 
CurrentAriaProperties: 
CurrentAriaRole: 
CurrentAutomationId: 
CurrentBoundingRectangle: <ctypes.wintypes.RECT object at 0x00000000037A2948>
CurrentClassName: PokerStarsListClass
CurrentControlType: 50033
CurrentControllerFor: <POINTER(IUIAutomationElementArray) ptr=0x9466250 at 37a2948>
CurrentCulture: 0
CurrentDescribedBy: <POINTER(IUIAutomationElementArray) ptr=0x9466370 at 37a2948>
CurrentFlowsTo: <POINTER(IUIAutomationElementArray) ptr=0x9466310 at 37a2948>
CurrentFrameworkId: Win32
CurrentHasKeyboardFocus: 0
CurrentHelpText: 
CurrentIsContentElement: 1
CurrentIsControlElement: 1
CurrentIsDataValidForForm: 0
CurrentIsEnabled: 1
CurrentIsKeyboardFocusable: 1
CurrentIsOffscreen: 0
CurrentIsPassword: 0
CurrentIsRequiredForForm: 0
CurrentItemStatus: 
CurrentItemType: 
CurrentLabeledBy: <POINTER(IUIAutomationElement) ptr=0x0 at 37a2948>
CurrentLocalizedControlType: pane
CurrentName: 
CurrentNativeWindowHandle: 1574328
CurrentOrientation: 0
CurrentProcessId: 11300
CurrentProviderDescription: [pid:6188,hwnd:0x1805B8 Main:Nested [pid:11300,hwnd:0x1805B8 Annotation(parent link):Microsoft: Annotation Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll); Main:Microsoft: MSAA Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]; Hwnd(parent link):Microsoft: HWND Proxy (unmanaged:uiautomationcore.dll)]
```

Comment: I don't see the question here. What are you struggling with?

Comment: The question is just: How can I command the pokerstars software to go up or down in the list of tables, given that I can select the corresponding uiELement

Comment: What type of control is that list?

Comment: How can I retrieve that type ? I have tried the ItemType property but that doesn't work

Comment: Well, I'm a little out of my depth here. I'm not fluent in UIAutomation. I would say that you need to make your question more clear. I could not discern it from two reads.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question, adding more details and explaining a bit more, please tell if it's still unclear. I also found out that the ControlType of the element I want to control is off type `pane`, but I don't find anything interesting in the doc off the pane: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749129(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you will need the control inside the pane. The pane I believe is the container for the list. Now, the list control itself may not support automation. Perhaps you could ask the software vendor if they support automation!  ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49137/discussion-between-edi9999-and-david-heffernan)