# Keystroke Device Tracing (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, keyboard, trace, keystroke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish Multiple Keyboards in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060512/how-to-distinguish-multiple-keyboards-in-delphi)

If I have two keyboards attached to the same computer, is it possible to trace which keyboard a keystroke came from, and if so, how can i do it in delphi?