# Reading and identifying multiple USB keyboards

Tags: delphi, usb

I'm in charge of technology at my local camera club, a not-for-profit charity in Malvern UK.  We have a database-centric competition management system which is home-brewed by me in Delphi 6 and now we wish to add a scoring system to it.  This entails attaching 5 x cheap-and-standard USB numeric keypads to a PC (using a USB hub) and being able to programmatically read the keystrokes from each keyboard as they are entered by the 5 judges.  Of course, they will hit their keys in a completely parallel and asynchronous way, so I need to identify which key has been struck by which judge, so as to assemble the scores (i.e. possible multiple keystrokes each) they have entered individually.

From what I can gather, Windows grabs the attention of keyboard devices and looks after the characer strings they produce, simply squirting the chars into the normal keyboard queue (and I have confirmed that by experiment!).  This won't do for my needs, as I really must collect the 5 sets of (possibly multiple) key-presses and allocate the received characters as 5 separate variables for the scoring system to manipulate thereafter.

Can anyone (a) suggest a method for doing this in Delphi and (b) offer some guide to the code that might be needed?  Whilst I am pretty Delphi-aware, I have no experience of accessing USB devices, or capturing their data.

Any help or guidance would be most gratefully received!

Comment: Windows provides [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/about-raw-input) for this purpose. Not for Delphi but shows what Raw Input can do: [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard). Harder than regular input but a lot easier than USB drivers etc.

Comment: @Jerry I don't think what you said here is accurate

Comment: Looks like this might be a duplicate question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060512/how-to-distinguish-multiple-keyboards-in-delphi

Answer (score 5):

Windows provides a [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/about-raw-input), which can be used for this purpose. In the reference at the link provided, one of the advantages is listed as:

> - An application can distinguish the source of the input even if it is
>     from the same type of device. For example, two mouse devices.

While this is more work than regular Windows input messages, it is a lot easier than writing USB device drivers.

One example of its use (while not written in Delphi) demonstrates what it can do, and provides some information on using it:

[Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard).